# i cant use in-IDE git since update android studio to bumblebee

Tags: git, android-studio-bumblebee

Since i updated android studio to latest bumblebee version cant use in-IDE git.

any git tool will be cancelled.but i can use git with command.

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Go to preferences > Version Control > Git
and check Use credential helper.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. that's worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these simple steps down below. This might work for you.

1. Try to remove your GitHub account from your Android Studio.    Located in ->File -> Settings --> GitHub
2. After that try to add your GitHub account again. I hope this might
   help.

Thank you and Happy Coding.

Comment: I've tried that but not woked. :/